# PowerShell op_Explicit from Object with only one property

Tags: class, type-conversion, powershell-core

I am dealing with a strange error i can't really understand. After boiling down my script to the bare minimum this is what happens. Basically I am trying to create a class which supports explicit conversation from a PSCustomObject (Background: I want my script to digest JSON files while ensuring the presence of certain properties)
The strange thing is, that the explicit conversation seems to work only when there are more then 1 properties in the input object.

```
class MyClass {
    [int]$MyNumber

    MyClass($MyNumber) {
        $this.MyNumber = $MyNumber
    }

    hidden static [MyClass] op_Explicit([psobject]$InputObject) {
        return [MyClass]::new($InputObject.Number)
    }
}

$MyObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Number = 5
}

[MyClass]$MyObject
```

The last line throws the error: `Cannot convert value "@{Number=5}" to type "MyClass". Error: "Exception setting "MyNumber": "Cannot convert the "@{Number=5}" value of type "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" to type "System.Int32".""`

```
class MyClass2 {
    [int]$MyNumber
    [int]$OtherNumber

    MyClass2($MyNumber, $OtherNumber) {
        $this.MyNumber = $MyNumber
        $this.OtherNumber = $OtherNumber
    }

    hidden static [MyClass2] op_Explicit([psobject]$InputObject) {
        return [MyClass2]::new($InputObject.Number, $InputObject.OtherNumber)
    }
}

$MyObject2 = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Number = 5
    OtherNumber = 1
}

[MyClass2]$MyObject2
```

Here everything works fine

I'am using PowerShell Core 7.3.7

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong and/or what is happening behind the curtain?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening in your first code block is that one of the ways PowerShell converts values to reference types is by invoking single pararameter constructors, and PowerShell is invoking your constructor rather than your conversion function.

If you change the constructor like below, so that the single parameter is an int, your code will work

```
MyClass([int]$MyNumber) {
    $this.MyNumber = $MyNumber
}
```